# Convert Json to Array variable (object)

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am trying to convert json to a variable without using `json_decode`.

For Example:

```
$json = '{
    "username": "username",
    "password": "pass",
    "movies": [
        {
            "a": "xx",
            "b": "xx",
            "c": "xx",
            "d": 1,
            "e": 2
        }
    ]
}';
```

I have tried to convert this into array:

```
    $post = array(
           'username' => 'username',
           'passsword' => 'pass',
           'movies' => (object) array(
             'a' => 'xx',
             'b' => 'xx',
             "c" => 1,
             "d" => 2
           )
    );
echo json_encode($post);
```

As you can see it does not match `movies` block. movies is an object. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: `echo json_encode($post['movies'],true);`

Comment: Why don't you want to use `json_decode` It is a perfect solution in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'movies' is an array of objects:

```
$post = array(
    'username' => 'username',
    'passsword' => 'pass',
    'movies' => array(
        (object) array(
            'a' => 'xx',
            'b' => 'xx',
            'c' => 1,
            'd' => 2.
        )
    )
);
```

But why don't you want to use json_decode()?

Comment: Because I was given JSON API (sample above). So I need to add the value of username, password, etc.

Comment: So what? `$array = json_decode($json, true); $array['newKey'] = 'newValue'; $newJson = json_encode($array);`

Answer (score 0):

Leaving aside why on earth you're specifically not using the function you should use...

`movies` is an array of objects, and objects are really just associative arrays. So it should be more like:

```
'movies' => Array(
    Array(
        "a" => "xx",
        "b" => "xx",
       ...
    )
),
```

Comment: Because I was given JSON API (sample above). So I need to add the value of username, password, etc in json?

Comment: What are you suggestion I should do?

Comment: `json_decode` it, modify the array, then `json_encode` the result.

Answer (score 0):

It should be `'movies' => array((object) array(`   not   `'movies' => (object) array(`

Example

```
echo "<pre>";
 $post = array(
           'username' => 'username',
           'passsword' => 'pass',
           'movies' => array((object) array(
             'a' => 'xx',
             'b' => 'xx',
             "c" => 1,
             "d" => 2
           ))
    );
echo json_encode($post)
```

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding it is that you are receiving an object. So lets convert that to json, and then convert that json object into an associative array.

```
$var = json_encode($post['movies'],true);
print_r(json_decode($var,true));
```